# Join on resultant table of another join without using subquery,CTE or temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

My question is can we join a table A to resultant table of inner join of table A and B without using subquery, CTE or temp tables ?

I am using SQL Server.

I will explain the situation with an example

The are two tables `GoaLScorers` and `GoalScoredDetails`.

GoaLScorers

```
gid    Name    
-----------
1       A
2       B
3       A
```

GoalScoredDetails

```
DetailId    gid     stadium     goals  Cards
---------------------------------------------
1            1        X          2       1  
2            2        Y          5       2
3            3        Y          2       1
```

The result I am expecting is if I select a stadium 'X' (or 'Y')

I should get name of all who may or may not have scored there, also aggregate total number of goals,total cards.

Null value is acceptable for names if no goals or no cards.

I can get the result I am expecting with the below query

```
SELECT
    gs.name, 
    SUM(goal) as TotalGoals, 
    SUM(cards) as TotalCards
FROM 
    (SELECT
         gid, stadium, goal, cards 
     FROM
         GoalScoredDetails 
     WHERE 
         stadium = 'Y') AS vtable
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    GoalScorers AS gs ON vtable.gid = gs.gid 
GROUP BY 
    gs.name
```

My question is can we get the above result without using a subquery or CTE or temp table ?

Basically what we need to do is `OUTER JOIN GoalScorers` to resultant virtual table of `INNER JOIN OF GoalScorers` and `GoalScoredDetails`.

But I am always faced with ambiguous column name error as "gid" column is present in `GoalScorers` and also in resultant table. Error persists even if I try to use alias for column names.

I have created a sql fiddle for this her: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40162/8

Comment: If you always use the table name or alias when referring to a column you will avoid the error.  Example: SELECT gid does not contain all the information SQL requires, while SELECT gs.gid does.

Comment: @destination-data  The main issue is how can I alias or specify the gid column inside the resultant table . Even if I assign an alias in select it cannot be used for joining , unless it is a subquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  gs.name, SUM(gsd.goal) AS totalGoals, SUM(gsd.cards) AS totalCards
FROM    GoalScorers gs
LEFT JOIN GoalScoredDetails gsd ON gsd.gid = gs.gid AND
                                   gsd.Stadium = 'Y'
GROUP BY gs.name;
```

IOW, you could push your where criteria onto joining expression.

Comment: Thanks . I knew they was a way to get this done but could not figure out how . Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

The error *Ambiguous column name 'ColumnName'* occurs when SQL Server encounters two or more columns with the same and it hasn't been told which to use.  You can avoid the error by prefixing your column names with either the full table name, or an alias if provided.  For the examples below use the following data:

Sample Data

```
DECLARE @GoalScorers TABLE
    (
        gid        INT,
        Name    VARCHAR(1)
    )
;

DECLARE @GoalScoredDetails TABLE
    (
        DetailId    INT,
        gid            INT,
        stadium        VARCHAR(1),
        goals        INT,    
        Cards        INT
    )
;

INSERT INTO @GoalScorers
    (
        gid,
        Name
    )
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (3, 'A')
;

INSERT INTO @GoalScoredDetails
    (
        DetailId,
        gid,
        stadium,
        goals,
        Cards
    )
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'x', 2, 1),
    (2, 2, 'y', 5, 2),
    (3, 3, 'y', 2, 1)
;
```

In this first example we recieve the error.  Why?  Because there is more than one column called gid it cannot tell which to use.

Failed Example

```
SELECT 
    gid        
FROM
    @GoalScoredDetails AS gsd
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN @GoalScorers as gs        ON gs.gid = gsd.gid
;
```

This example works because we explicitly tell SQL which gid to return:

Working Example

```
SELECT 
    gs.gid        
FROM
    @GoalScoredDetails AS gsd
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN @GoalScorers as gs        ON gs.gid = gsd.gid
;
```

You can, of course, return both:

Example

```
SELECT 
    gs.gid,       
    gsd.gid
FROM
    @GoalScoredDetails AS gsd
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN @GoalScorers as gs        ON gs.gid = gsd.gid
;
```

In multi table queries I would always recommend prefixing every column name with a table/alias name.  This makes the query easier to follow, and reduces the likelihood of this sort of error.